# toggleClass on click for n <div> elements

Tags: jquery

I have code that creates buttons and divs with jquery and that button can toggle div.
How to toggle n divs without having to write code for every button and div created (guessing numbers of creation), like this what I got now:

```
<script>
  $("#place").on("click", "#odkat", function() {
    $(this).next( "#odbr" ).toggleClass( "odbro" );
  });
  $("#place").on("click", "#odkat_1", function() {
    $(this).next( "#odbr_1" ).toggleClass( "odbro" );
  });
  $("#place").on("click", "#odkat_2", function() {
    $(this).next( "#odbr_2" ).toggleClass( "odbro" );
  });
  $("#place").on("click", "#odkat_3", function() {
    $(this).next( "#odbr_3" ).toggleClass( "odbro" );
  });
  $("#place").on("click", "#odkat_4", function() {
    $(this).next( "#odbr_4" ).toggleClass( "odbro" );
  });
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector here:

```
$("#place").on("click", "[id^='odkat']", function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass( "odbro" );
});
```

Comment: it should be `[id^='odkat_'], #odkat` because the first one does not match the given selector

Answer (score 2):

The solution will be is to use classes instead of ids like

```
$("#place").on("click", ".odkat", function() {
   $(this).next().toggleClass( "odbro" );
});
```

The add the class `odkat` to the elements with id `odkat*`